# Awk - count the occurences of a value in a column

Tags: linux, awk

My aim is to run an awk code to check the value of column 4 and assign the count of its occurrence against it. My data looks like this

```
DN  Area    Peri    FID DN2 Area2   Peri2   FID2  
1   70  39  1066    1   47  29  3  
1   70  39  1083    1   1142    262 11  
1   4662    465 1085    1   23  19  16  
1   4662    465 1085    1   47  29  9  
1   4662    465 1085    1   1142    262 11  
1   280 78  1087    1   513 126 18  
1   23  19  1093    1   47  29  12  
1   93  48  1094    1   93  48  19  
1   117 48  1100    1   466 136 17  
1   326 126 1131    1   723 223 54  
1   326 126 1131    1   513 126 18  
1   23  19  1135    1   723 136 32  
1   47  29  1138    1   1702    281 49  
1   187 87  1150    1   47  29  40  
1   23  19  1153    1   187 78  47  
1   2191    397 1156    1   23  19  24  
1   2191    397 1156    1   47  29  20  
1   2191    397 1156    1   5524    581 87  
1   256 87  1157    1   466 136 41
```

Expected outcome:

```
1  
1  
3  
3 I
3  
1  
1  
1  
1  
2  
2  
1  
1  
1  
1  
3  
3  
3  
1
```

when I run the code I've written I get a '>' and the command doesnt stop running

```
awk '{if ( FNR>1 && count[$4]=i ) { for(i=1; i<=NR; ++i) printf "%d\n", i}} file
```

Comment: You get a `>` with that because your shell is waiting for a closing single quote to end the string that is awk's first argument. The `>` is its continuation prompt.

Comment: You should add a single quote just before the file.  `awk '{....}' file`

Comment: rookie mistake.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]++;next} FNR!=NR && FNR>1{print $4,a[$4]}'  Input_file Input_file
```

Above will print 4th column and its occurrence value both, in case you need only occurrence value then remove `$4` from `print` part in above code.

Comment: the script is giving me output 20 printed against $4 which is basically the total number of values in $4

Comment: @mcontoor, sorry it is not clear, please explain it more clearly and let me know then.

Comment: The output is 19 rows of "20" (20 being the total number of rows in the file.) I think a[$4] is counting the total no. of rows in $4 instead of the total number of occurences of the values

Comment: @mcontoor That's not what that script prints out. Are you sure you ran the right code?

Answer (score 1):

Read the file twice: Count the occurences in the first run (`NR==FNR`) and print them out in the second run (`FNR<NR`).

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$4]++}FNR<NR{print a[$4]}' file file
```

This counting also includes the headline, skip it if you don't want it.

Comment: the script is giving me output 20 printed against $4 which is basically the total number of values in $4

Comment: @mcontoor Sorry, I do not understand. The output is exactly the same as posted below "expected outcome".

Comment: @mcontoor this solution works fine are you sure you don't have a problem with your input file ?

Comment: it worked when i specified delimiter! Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In a single pass [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) you can do (with the assumption you do not want to count the header)

```
awk '{ a[NR]=$4; c[$4]++ }END{for(i=2;i<=NR;++i) print c[a[i]] }' file
```